# Initializing generic type fields in the class itself

Tags: java, class, generics, field, instance

Here is the code...

```
public class Dog {

}


public class Bird {

}


public class Animal< T > {
    T field1 = (T) new Bird();  // unchecked cast : Bird to T

    public void display() {
        System.out.println(field1);
    }
}
```

I was expecting run time error, but it runs fine....

It is giving me output:

```
com.company.Bird@48140564
```

in main class

```
public static void main(){
    Animal<Dog> animal = new Animal();
    animal.display();   // I was expecting run time error here

}
```

Comment: What is the question? What problems are you facing?

Comment: That’s precisely what the “*unchecked* cast” warning is telling you, the validity of this construct will not be checked at runtime. Some constructs may fail, others not, which makes this so problematic. It may fail at a place far away from the code where the heap pollution originally happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not getting error because the code is still "valid". Java Generics is a fancy way to handle objects cast and improve type checking. Every time you use a generic, when you compile the code Java will convert them in a explicit cast. Main reason is related to legacy with Java versions before the generics has been introduced, so Java handles them like "Object" class and then cast them for you when required.

Example, in your .java file you write the following code:

```
String hello = new String();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(hello);

Object noCastRequired = list.get(0);
String castRequired = list.get(0);
```

In its relative .class file, Java is going to write:

```
String hello = new String();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(hello);
Object noCastRequired = list.get(0);
String castRequired = (String)list.get(0);
```

If you're going to check your compiled code, you can see that expression is still a valid code statement, but you're going to have errors and troubles if you try to "use" that field in a method where the "type" is required; print statement accepts an object class a parameter, so Java is not going to cast it.

Example:

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Root<FirstLevel> correct = new Root<>();

        Root<FirstLevelChild> iAmNotValid = new Root<>(); // No error
        Root<SecondLevel> iAmNotValidToo = new Root<>(); // No error

        System.out.println(correct.field.first); // Ok
        System.out.println(iAmNotValid.field.first); // Ko, because java.lang.ClassCastException: FirstLevel cannot be cast to FirstLevelChild
        System.out.println(iAmNotValidToo.field.second);
    }


}

class Root<T> {
    public T field = (T) new FirstLevel();
}

class FirstLevel {
    public String first = "First";
}

class SecondLevel {
    public String second = "Second";
}

class FirstLevelChild extends FirstLevel {
}
```

Comment: ok, so in your Root<T> class "new FirstLevel()" is casted to T. What does that mean. Suppose in main class if you provide the actual parameter as other class which is not related with your FirstLevel class than shouldn't it give me error.

Comment: When you provide a class which is not related to FirstLevel, like Root<SecondLevel>, code is still valid for compilation because Java will convert T in Object, so T field = (T) new FirstLevel() will be Object field = new FirstLevel(). When I am going to use "field" where the T type is required, ClassCastException is going to be thrown because Java will put in the .class file (SecondLevel) field. This runtime error is thrown even if you use a class related to FirstLevel, like FirstLevelChild because field is going always to be "FirstLevel" object so (FirstLevelChild) field is not a valid cast.

Comment: Thank you very much; can you provide me the link so that I can read more about this. it will be very helpful for me.; :)

Comment: You can read http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Topic3 or any Oracle Java reference book

Comment: @sparshgoyal does the answer help you?